# How to separate tabs into multiple rows in tab control (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a tab control which I add tab items to programatically using C# and WPF. Everything works ok and I have tabs that look like this:

tab1       tab2        tab3

..tabs wrap around..

tab12      tab13

However, what I want to do is have two distinct rows of tabs like follows

tab4   tab5   tab6

...separator line...

tab1       tab2        tab3

..tabs wrap around..

tab12      tab13

Any idea how to accomplish this? My current tab control style looks like this

```
        <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,4,4,4"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F9F9F9"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <WrapPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Column="0" IsItemsHost="true" Margin="2,2,2,0" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPanel" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="0" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ContentSource="SelectedContent" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>

                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" TargetName="ContentPanel" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition0" Value="Auto"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" TargetName="ColumnDefinition1" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition0" Value="*"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="RowDefinition1" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderPanel" Value="2,2,0,2"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

so I figured I would add a second wrap panel to put the other tabs into. However, how do I specify which tabs would go into it?

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying the MaxWidth for the only column of the grid, where the WrapPanel is defined ?
As for the second question, regarding to multiple WrapPanels, that's a good option as well. You can check the ActualWidth of the first WrapPanel in code and if its more than the width of the window, you can then target new tabs into the second panel.

Comment: If I set the max width for the grid column to something smaller than the window size it just makes everything go into a smaller tab control -- not what I want. How would I target tabs to go into the second panel?

Comment: Here is a crazy idea: you can have the tab header template empty - so there is nothing created on tab creation. And on the tab control you register for "TabOpened" control, and add a custom code to add custom controls (as tab headers) into the desired panels. The custom control onclick is handled by a code, which activates the associated tab behind the scene.